# Springboot Microservices slow responses

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

My project is developed in Springboot with eureka, zuul, ribbon and It deployed on GCP kubernetes cluster. If I try to rest calls through postman It works fine but take long time(1s-2s) to get the response. I have tried to do a load test for the server. Following shows the result of that load test. But consider that this request is not connecting to the database, it only hit the point and return hardcoded value.

```
Running 30s test @ https://xxx.coo:443/api/v1/lo/test/test1
  100 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.23s   162.00ms   1.42s    45.45%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00    100.00%
  333 requests in 30.07s, 168.96KB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 300
  Non-2xx or 3xx responses: 200
Requests/sec:     11.08
Transfer/sec:      5.62KB
```

Why request/sec is this low? How should I configure the servers to handle more load?

Here is my configurations. Consider that discovery server, zuul api and other client servers run as different springboot projects.

Discovery Server application.properties file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server

server:
  port: 8070

eureka:
  environment: production
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    service-url:
      defaultZone : ${DIS_SERVER}
```

Zuul Gateway application.properties file

```
 zuul:
  prefix: /api/v1
  routes:
    g1-server:
      path: /g1/**
      serviceId: G1-SERVER
    g2-server:
      path: /g2/**
      serviceId: G2-SERVER

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server

server:
  port: 5000

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone : ${DIS_SERVER}

spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignored-interfaces:
        - eth0
        - eth1
        - eth2
        - eth3
        - lo
        - veth.*

ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 200000
  ReadTimeout: 200000
```

I have used restTemplate to call other microservices. following code shows how I use the restTemplate to call other microservices.

```
String g1Url = "http://g1-server/ud/{id}";
String g1Response = restTemplate.getForObject(g1Url, String.class, id);
```

Comment: Are you using @LoadBalanced annotation for your rest template ?

Comment: @yongsung.yoon Yes. I am using it.